# How to set xml DOCTYPE with Delphi / ADOM (OpenXML)?

Tags: xml, delphi, openxml, doctype

Using Adom 4.3, creating a new document with

```
DI := TDomImplementation.Create;
Doc := TDomDocumentNS.Create( DI )
```

How do I set the

```
<!DOCTYPE ...
```

line in the resulting XML doc?
/not with inserting this line in a stringlist at the saving of the file/

The Doctypedecl property of the document is read only and actually NIL after creating the document, so how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let the DOM implementation create an instance of `IDOMDocumentType` which you can use when creating the document:

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Xml.adomxmldom,
  Xml.XmlDom,
  Xml.XmlDoc;

procedure Main;
var
  DomImpl: IDOMImplementation;
  Doc: TXMLDocument;
begin
  DomImpl := GetDOM(sAdom4XmlVendor);
  Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    Doc.DOMVendor := GetDOMVendor(sAdom4XmlVendor);
    Doc.DOMDocument := DomImpl.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg:svg',
      DomImpl.createDocumentType('svg:svg', '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN',
      'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'));
    Doc.SaveToFile(ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0), '.xml'));
  finally
    Doc.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ExitCode := 1;
      Writeln(Format('[%s] %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]));
    end;
  end;
end.
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg:svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" >
<svg:svg/>
```